# Setting configuration properties to access in REPL

Tags: scala, sbt, typesafe-config

Given:

*src/test/scala/net/Main.scala*

```
package net

import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

object Main extends App {
    override def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val bar   = ConfigFactory.load().getString("app.bar")
        val bippy = ConfigFactory.load().getString("app.bippy")
        println(s"bar: $bar | bippy : $bippy")
    }
}
```

*src/test/resources/application.conf*

```
app {
    bar = ${?BAR}
    bippy = ${?BIPPY}
}
```

I attempted to set the `BAR` and `BIPPY` environment variables in `sbt`:

`>set envVars := Map("BAR" -> "bar!", "BIPPY" -> "bippy!")`

Then, I opened the REPL in test mode:

`>test:console`

```
scala> import net.Main
import net.Main

scala> Main.main(Array())
com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting 
    found for key 'app.bar'
```

How can I set these properties for the REPL?

Answer (score 1):

Pass your configuration file using the `-Dconfig.file` system property

```
[localhost]$ sbt -Dconfig.file=src/test/resources/application.conf
[info] Loading global plugins from ~/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from ~/my/project
[info] Set current project to my-project (in build file:~/my/project/)
> console
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info] 
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.6 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_72-internal).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import com.typesafe.config._
import com.typesafe.config._

scala> val config = ConfigFactory.load()
config: com.typesafe.config.Config = Config(SimpleConfigObject({"test": "success"})

scala> val value = config.getString("test")
value: String = test
```